# Azure CLI filtering with JMESPath for child property that is set to null

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, jmespath

I'm using the Azure CLI to query Azure DevOps pull requests.

E.g.:

```
az repos pr list --status completed
```

This returns data similar to:

```json
[
  {
    "artifactId": null,
    "autoCompleteSetBy": null,
    "closedBy": null,
    "closedDate": "2023-02-11T01:13:31.341293+00:00",
    "codeReviewId": 12345,
    "commits": null,
    "completionOptions": {
      "autoCompleteIgnoreConfigIds": [],
      "bypassPolicy": null,
      "bypassReason": null,
      "deleteSourceBranch": null,
      "mergeCommitMessage": "Merged PR 12345",
      "mergeStrategy": "noFastForward",
      "squashMerge": null,
      "transitionWorkItems": true,
      "triggeredByAutoComplete": null
    }
  },
  {
    "artifactId": null,
    "autoCompleteSetBy": null,
    "closedBy": null,
    "closedDate": "2023-03-04T23:59:53.506941+00:00",
    "codeReviewId": 12346,
    "commits": null,
    "completionOptions": {
      "autoCompleteIgnoreConfigIds": [],
      "bypassPolicy": null,
      "bypassReason": null,
      "deleteSourceBranch": true,
      "mergeCommitMessage": "Merged PR 12346",
      "mergeStrategy": "noFastForward",
      "squashMerge": null,
      "transitionWorkItems": true,
      "triggeredByAutoComplete": null
    }
  }
]
```

I want to find just the items in the array that have `completionOptions.deleteSourceBranch` set to null.

I've tried setting `--query` to the following (I'm using PowerShell), but it always returns an empty array.

- `"[?!completionOptions.deleteSourceBranch]"`
- `"[?completionOptions.deleteSourceBranch == null]"`
- ``` "[?completionOptions.deleteSourceBranch != ``true``]" ```
- ``` "[?completionOptions.deleteSourceBranch == ``null``]" ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Both `[?completionOptions.deleteSourceBranch == null]` and ```[?completionOptions.deleteSourceBranch == `null`]``` should work, purely JMESPath speaking.